# How to handle OdataException in DefaultODataPathHandler.Parse at global level?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, odata

```
DefaultODataPathHandler.Parse(string serviceRoot, string odataPath, IServiceProvider requestContainer)
```

is throwing `ODataException` when I try to send a wrong data type to a 
OData controller function. For example, calling `GetOrders(date = 20181001)`, (with an integer instead of a date (2018-10-01)), throws ODataException with message:

> not able to cast `Edm.Int32` to `Emd.DateTime`

How can I handle this exception at global level?

Comment: Use a try/catch perhaps? Why don't you simply fix the bug that is causing the exception?

Comment: Take the [tour], read [Ask], and [MCVE].